# Categorize E-mail on Iphone

Tags: iphone

I use categories to classify the e-mail in my inbox (Microsoft Outlook 2010).  I have not been able to figure out how (and if it's even possible) to categorize e-mail from my iphone.  Has anyone accomplished this?

Comment: What mail server are you using? Why not use Outlook on the iPhone? we'll need details to make progress on this...

Answer (score 1):

(This answer assumes you are running iOS 7 or later, and that you mean Outlook.com mail.)

You are certainly able to categorise your mail in Outlook.com mail. However, if you set up your Outlook account before September 2013, this may be your issue.

The two most popular email standards are POP3 and IMAP4. IMAP4 is preferred because of push mail and the ability to categorise your email. POP3 lacks these features. Before September 2013, Microsoft did not implement IMAP4 capability in Outlook.com, forcing users to use the inferior POP3 standard.

## Possible Solutions

**1. Check that you know how to use mailboxes**: From Mail, go into the root of the app. You should see all of your accounts listed. Tap [Outlook] if you do. If you don't (i.e. Outlook is your only account), you are already in the Outlook menu. Next, tap [Edit] and then [New Mailbox]. The rest is self explanatory. To move mail into mailboxes, open the message and tap the folder icon. Then, choose the mailbox that you want to move the mail into. Easy! If you still can't see the mailbox options...

**2. Delete and set up your Outlook.com account in Mail, Contacts, Calendars**: You will not lose any content by doing this, as all data is stored in the cloud. Simply open Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars, and delete your Outlook account. Then, set it up again. This should force your iPhone to use the newer, IMAP4 capable settings. If you are still unable to create mailboxes...

**3. Set up IMAP4 settings manually**: Using the settings available on [this page](http://outlook.com), enter Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account > Other and set up the Outlook.com account manually.